# Convert a through-hole type circuit board to SMD type

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, components, surface-mount, component-selection, power-factor-correction

I want to replace the through hole parts of the following circuit with SMD parts (control section.) This is an 80W FPC using L6562A. Is this a straightforward action or does it require further considerations?

What are the considerations for each part replacement listed below?

- bridge rectifier
- resistors (dividers)
- resistors (controlling networks)
- ceramic capacitors (controlling networks)
- diode and Zener (controlling networks)

Is there any other component in this circuit to replace?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a problem. Straightforward. Just make sure to match or exceed the voltage and power ratings. SMD components tend to be smaller and more compact so tend to have lower ratings. Your main issue is that you may not be able to find a full-wave rectifier in SMD form but you can always just use four diodes. You could potentially replace C1, Q1, D1, and the NTC as well. But SMD is harder to heatsink for Q1, and NTC may be difficult to find.

Comment: Also pay attention to resistor power dissipation - for example r4/r5 are likely separate resistors to avoid using a bigger one - you might need to replace them with 3 or 4 that add up to the same amount depending on the SMT resistors you choose

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, 1. challenging myself    2.size-reduction

Comment: @Taniwha No, most likely it is not about power dissipation, but the maximum voltage the resistors are rated, even if they can handle the power dissipation. Kamran it is straightforward but complex - unless there is no documentation, you must guess why a part with certain ratings is selected and if it is important or not due to safety regulations that will differ in each country. It reads it is a demo board for evaluation purposes only - it does not mean it will pass safety and compliance tests so even if you did replace all parts with SMD equivalents you might still not be able to sell it.

Comment: @Justme thanks for your recommendation. I don't want to sell it. it is just an experimental study. an application note is also published for this topology.

Comment: Would you know how to start this design from data sheets if you didn't have the example hardware? That example hardware may misdirect you.

Comment: If it for size reduction, pay attention that you must provide minimum isolation distances. You can't just pack everything together the closest you can using the smallest compatible components.

Comment: @ Blup1980 thanks for your recommendation Blup, is there any document or book explaining how to design the new proper PCB layout providing considerations like minimum isolation distances and traces' width? please share the link